# iOS : No Notification Received from Facebook App Request

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-requests

I have to integrate app request on my app but it doesn't seem to work. I searched about it and I can't find a clear answer. Some replies from the reports said that the request can be found in [Facebook App Center](https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/requests) but I didn't receive any request and also, no notification was received.

I'm using `Facebook SDK for  iOS v3.8` to send the request. There's no error and there's a request, it was always successful but still no notification.

Here is the code I'm using to send the request.

```
- (void)sendAppInvite:(NSString *)message {
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"app_non_users", @"filters", nil];

    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:[FBSession activeSession] message:message title:nil parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // Case A: Error launching the dialog
            NSLog(@"Error on app invite.");
        } else {
            if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                NSLog(@"User canceled app invite");
            } else {
                // Case C: Dialog shown and the user clicks Cancel or Share
                NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                    // User clicked the Cancel button
                    NSLog(@"User canceled app invite");
                } else {
                    // User clicked the Send button
                    NSString *postID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                    NSLog(@"Request successful: %@", postID);
                }
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

I also tried to build the sample app from `Facebook`, I sent an invite. Still, no notification and no request from the app center.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Also, is there a bug from `Facebook Request`?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same problem.

Comment: I really didn't know what happened. I tested it again last week, and my friend seen the request although not in the notifications but in the app center.

Comment: yes, that is right. I realized my notifications being sent to App Center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only apps that are actually on facebook.com can use the Notifications API.  Note this is different than "app requests".  In other words, you can't get your app to post a notification in the top right corner where the globe is.

Comment: So, that's why my friend got my request, when he visited the app center, but no notification? Thanks!

Comment: Precisely.  Stinks, but it's the way it is.  Accept answer pls :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to Add app in your developer account

facebook -> Apps -> "You app" -> Setting -> add platform -> App on Facebook -> Add any URl

Now you will get app request notification

Comment: i did not get the notification can you please help :)

Answer (score 0):

you Set enable in sandbox mode in facebook developer

[Visit](https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fapps)

In your Facebook go to games->apps->app request and see app notification